# Scanning the screen in Java?

Tags: java, colors, screenshot, pixel, awtrobot

I need a short method that **gives me the color of a point with given coordinates**. I heard of a Robot class that can take screenshots, but I don't really know how to use it.

Comment: `but I don't really know how to use it.` - How did you hear about it? What method from the class is confusing you? Did you read the API? Did you search the forum/web for examples?

Answer (score 1):

The #getPixelColor(int,int) method will do this.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#getPixelColor(int,%20int)

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
Color pixelColor = robot.getPixelColor(xPos, yPos);
```